# Define SpoutConfig parameter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

I have a Storm topology in which I am using `KafkaSpout`.

```
BrokerHosts zk = new ZkHosts("localhost:2181");
SpoutConfig spoutConf = new SpoutConfig(zk, "topic", "/topic", "discovery");
```

I want to know 3rd and 4th parameter which is passed in `SpoutConfig`.

- Is 3rd parameter, the Zookeeper root path where Zookeeper is install or the `dataDir` path?
- The 4th parameter is an ID, but I don't know why it is used and what should I have to give?

Answer (score 1):

zkRoot and id are used to construct the zookeeper path under which storm stores the kafka offset.  You can read about it [here](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-contrib/tree/master/storm-kafka#using-kafkaspout).

> The spout stores the state of the offsets its consumed in Zookeeper. The spout is parameterized with the root path to store the offsets and an id for this particular spout. So offsets for partitions will be stored in these paths, where "0", "1" are ids for the partitions:
>
> {root path}/{id}/0
>    {root path}/{id}/1 
>   {root path}/{id}/2 
>   {root path}/{id}/3
>   ...